# JavaScript setHours is setting less hours than specified by parameter

Tags: visualforce, javascript, datetime, date, function

```
    function removeDaysToDate(date, hours){
                    var res = new Date(date);
                    console.log('res ->' + res);
                    console.log('hours ->' + hours);
                    res.setHours(res.getDate() - hours);
                    console.log('updated res ->' + res);
                    return res;
                }

//res -> :: Mon Sep 27 2021 09:37:16 GMT+0200
//hours -> :: 24
//updated res ->:: Mon Sep 27 2021 03:37:16 GMT+0200
```

The problem is, this function was working perfectly until last Friday 24th september. On this day, the function starting removing **12 hours** instead of 24 specified. And, today, **it's removing 6 hours.** I'm working in Visualforce Page.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subtracting the hours from the day of the month. Notice how it was working on the 24th, which means you were doing 24-24, which equals 0. You'll want to use getHours() instead:

```
function removeDaysToDate(date, hours){
    var res = new Date(date);
    console.log('res ->' + res);
    console.log('hours ->' + hours);
    res.setHours(res.getHours() - hours);
    console.log('updated res ->' + res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks!